# SOQL: Select Opportunity based on Product fields

Tags: soql, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I am trying to query Opportunities which have a Product matching certain criteria on, something like below:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE type != 'renewal' 
  AND Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId 
             FROM OpportunityLineItem 
             WHERE pricebookentry.product2.custom__c = 'value')
```

While the above doesn't cause an error no rows are returned. Is this possible or is my soql not formed correctly?

Edit:
Splitting the SOQLS, the Opportunity part returns rows as expected. The OpportunityLineItem part doesn't:

```
SELECT OpportunityId
FROM OpportunityLineItem
WHERE pricebookentry.product2.custom__c = 'value'
```

So I believe I am doing something wrong with the OLI to Product part: `pricebookentry.product2.custom__c`

Comment: Did you try both query ("Select ... From Opportunity WHERE Type" ... and "SELECT FROM OppLineItem ...") ? Did they return something ?

Comment: Yes I've added some more detail to my question.

Comment: Your OLI query looks ok. Do you have any products with custom__c = 'value'? and do you have any added to an opportunity? As nothing is returned from your OLI query then I would suggest your filter is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was elsewhere in the class and not with the SOQL in my post. It is working as intended now.